# Convert list of repeated column names and list of values into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have two lists.  One contains a list of headers that is repeated. And one contains values.  See example below:

```
cols = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3']
values = [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 1]
```

How would I create a dataframe from such a structure with three columns ('col1', 'col2', 'col3') and two rows.

Desired result

```
'col1', 'col2', 'col3'
1,3,4
6,7,1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try converting `values` to series, then groupby on `cols` and agg to list, finally convert to dataframe and transpose

```
s = pd.Series(values).groupby(cols).agg(list)
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(s.to_dict())
```

---

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     3     4
1     6     7     1
```

Or using defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in zip(cols,values):
        d[k].append(v)
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `cols` and `values` are simply repeated (making both structured lists with a set order and alignment operations are unneeded) we can simply convert `values` to an [`array`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) and [`reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html) based on the [`unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) column values:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

cols = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3']
values = [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 1]

# Unique Col Values
u_cols = np.unique(cols)
# Build DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.array(values).reshape(-1, len(u_cols)),
    columns=u_cols
)
```

`df`:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     3     4
1     6     7     1
```

Or as a csv:

```
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False, quotechar="'", quoting=2)
```

`output.csv`:

```
'col1','col2','col3'
1,3,4
6,7,1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
import csv


cols = ["col1", "col2", "col3", "col1", "col2", "col3"]
values = [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 1]

df = (
    pd.DataFrame(zip(cols, values))
    .pivot(columns=0, values=1)
    .apply(sorted, key=pd.isna)
    .dropna()
)
print(df.to_csv(index=False, quotechar="'", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC))
```

Prints:

```
'col1','col2','col3'
1.0,3.0,4.0
6.0,7.0,1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the things to a dict and then access the values from the keys

```py
cols = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3']
values = [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 1]

the_dict = {
    key: [x[1] for x in zip(cols, values) if x[0] == key] 
    for key in set(cols)
}

print(the_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Get `n`, the unique number of values in `cols` column, then iterate the values, and cols list parallel using `zip` on equal chunk, and create dictionary out of it, finally pass it to `pd.DataFrame`

```py
n = len(set(cols))
pd.DataFrame([{k: v for k, v in zip(cols[i:i + n+1], values[i:i + n+1])}for i in range(0,len(cols), n)])
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
**OUTPUT:**
   col1  col2  col3
0     6     3     4
1     6     7     1
```